# RadioButton set fill color of the circle

Tags: android, layout, colors, radio-button

In my layout I have an `AppCompatRadioButton`. With `app:buttonTint` I make the button white. If I checked the `AppCompatRadioButton` the fill color of the circle is also white. How can I change only the fill color of the circle when the button is checked? Example: On click the circle is furthermore white and the fill color of the circle would be change to red.

Comment: Did you try using a custom background, and/or tinkering with the theme? I'm fairly confident you will find your solution there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use custom layer

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radioButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:checked="true"
                        android:text="Text"
                        android:button="@drawable/selector_radio"
                        android:textSize="16dp" />
```

selector_radio.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/radio_layer" android:state_checked="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/radio_ring_checked"></item>
</selector>
```

radio_layer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/radio_ring_checked"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/radio_ring_unchecked"/>

</layer-list>
```

radio_ring_checked.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadiusRatio="4"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thickness="2dp"
    android:useLevel="false" >

    <solid android:color="@color/ash" />

    <size
        android:height="30dp"
        android:width="30dp" />

</shape>
```

radio_ring_unchecked.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadiusRatio="1000"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thickness="4dp"
    android:useLevel="false" >

    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryButton" />

    <size
        android:height="18dp"
        android:width="18dp" />

</shape>
```

Comment: very nice and helpful answer. Work's very nice. Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1** If you want you change just a color you can use theme.

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="MyCheckBox" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#d1d1d1</item>   <!-- normal border color change as you wish -->
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#359e1d</item> <!-- activated color change as you wish -->
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFF3F3C</item> <!-- checkbox text color -->
  </style>
```

**In Your Layout**

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/radioButton"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:checked="true"
                            android:text="Text"
                            android:theme="@style/MyCheckBox"
                            android:textSize="16dp" />
```

**Step 2** If you want to change icon of rabio button

**In Your Layout**

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                                android:id="@+id/radioButton"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:checked="true"
                                android:text="Text"
                                android:button="@drawable/cb_selector"
                                android:textSize="16dp" />
```

**Your drawable**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/icon_tick" />
        <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/icon_un_tick" />
    </selector>
```